# How to export certs with SAN extensions?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have this PowerShell command that exports for me all issued certificates into a `.csv` file:

```
$Local = "$PSScriptRoot"

$File = "$Local\IssuedCerts.csv"

$Header = "Request ID,Requester Name,Certificate Template,Serial Number,Certificate Effective Date,Certificate Expiration Date,Issued Country/Region,Issued Organization,Issued Organization Unit,Issued Common Name,Issued City,Issued State,Issued Email Address"

certutil -view -out $Header csv > $File
```

This works fine. I would like to format the output in a more readable manner, if it's somehow possible, please let me know, too.

The point is I need to export all certificates which will expire soon, but I also need data from SAN Extensions from each certificate to be exported with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps getting the certificates directly from the CertificateAuthority [X509Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=netframework-4.7.2) and reading the certificate extensions (one of which is the Subject Alt Names) using the [ASNEncodedData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asnencodeddata?view=netframework-4.7.2) class would do the trick?

Example code below on reading certificates from the given store and printing out their extensions:

```
using namespace System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

$caStore = [X509Store]::new([StoreName]::CertificateAuthority, [StoreLocation]::LocalMachine)
$caStore.Open([OpenFlags]::ReadOnly)

foreach ($certificate in $caStore.Certificates) {
   foreach ($extension in $certificate.Extensions) {
      $asnData = [System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData]::new($extension.Oid, $extension.RawData)
      Write-Host "Extension Friendly Name: $($extension.Oid.FriendlyName)"
      Write-Host "Extension OID: $($asnData.Oid.Value)"
      Write-Host "Extension Value: $($asnData.Format($true))"
   }
}

$caStore.Close()
```

You can specify a different store to open by specifying a different value for the `[StoreName]::CertificateAuthority` section.

Disclaimer, I haven't been able to test this code in production, so I'm not 100% certain that all the fields you require are exposed, but may serve as a good starting point